# I've got "Target container is not a DOM element" error on my codesandbox with react & parcel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parcel, codesandbox

My project was working on my computer but now on `CodeSanbox` I've got an error

> Target container is not a DOM element

The project is just a template project using `react` & `parcel`.
I didn't change anything between my home project and the one on codesanbox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React App w/ Parcel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.scss";

const App = () => {
  return <div />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

[github repo](https://github.com/Nolat/react-app-parcel)

Comment: Try adding `type="text/babel"` to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a clash with the keyword `app`.
You can simply rename the div to `root` or similar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React App w/ Parcel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.scss";

const App = () => {
  return <div />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-app-parcel-g9ff8

Comment: Ok thanks you it worked ! Just one question, why would it worked on my mac at home and not on codesandbox ?

Comment: This was a saver. Thanks!